# Rearrange Array by Most Popular & Have 1 instance of each using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to arrange array by most popular(most occurring) and then only have one instance of each.

For Instance,

```
Array ( [0] => cat [1] => dog [2] => bird [3] => dog [4] => dog [5] => cat [6] => turtle )
```

Would be:

```
Array ( [0] => dog [1] => cat [2] => bird [3] => turtle )
```

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: time for a map / reduce job !

Answer (score 1):

Combine the [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and the [arsort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) functions. Something like this:

```
$a = array('cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'turtle');
$a = array_count_values($a); // creating a 'name' => 'occurrence count' array
arsort($a); // sorting them reverse order and maintaining keys
$ordered_animals = array_keys($a); // getting the keys in a separate array
```

Comment: How would you go about only showing the values that had a Array_Count_Value of 2 or More?

Comment: Maybe [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and an anonymous callback function. Or if this is a huge array maybe [FilterIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this:

```
$reversed = array();
foreach($unsorted as $key => $val){
  if(!isset($reversed[$val])) $reversed[$val] = 0;
  $reversed[$val]++;
}

$sorted = array_keys(asort($reversed));
```

Comment: after reading @complex857 you should use his solution with `array_count_values` with is whet I do in the foreach loop - forgot about this function ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = array( 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'hello', 'world', 'dog', 'hello', 'ok' ); // etc

$valueCount = array_count_values( $items );

arsort( $valueCount );

$keys = array_keys( $valueCount );
```